# Doesn't want to show the pop up window on click of Quick action

Tags: apex, visualforce, quickaction

I have created a Visualforce page and added it to a Quick Action.

On this page, I've implemented the Apex method that runs the Batch class. However, I don't want to display a popup or modal during this process; I prefer the entire operation to run in the background when the user clicks on the button. Could you please help me with this?

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" tabStyle="Account"  extensions="ExecuteSchedulerController" action="{!excuteBatch}" showQuickActionVfHeader="false" >
</apex:page>
```

Apex Method:

```
 public PageReference excuteBatch() {
    Id pageId =  ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    PageReference accountRecordView;
    try{
        SendCaseReportViaEmail batch= new SendCaseReportViaEmail();
        database.executeBatch(batch);
        accountRecordView = new PageReference('/' + pageId);
        accountRecordView.setRedirect(true);
        
    }
    catch(exception ex){
        system.debug('line ' + ex.getLineNumber()+'cause'+ex.getCause()+'message '+ex.getMessage()+'Stack'+ex.getStackTraceString());
    }
    return accountRecordView;  
}
```

Comment: Can you work with LWC or Aura, there we can handle this problem.

Comment: Yes, I have searched on Google there is lots of content to fix this problem in Aura or LWC but my preference is to implement this functionality directly within Visualforce Pages (VFP) without relying on Aura or LWC components. Is it possible to achieve this within VFP?